Ability to retrieve multiple metafields via GraphQL in Shopify
I created some Metafields for Blog Posts and have them populated. I'm building a Hydrogen Shopify storefront and using GraphQL to fetch that blog/article data. But I can't seem to figure out how to get all the metafields. Seems like 'metafield' and 'metafields' only return a single field based on key and namespace. Is there a way to more than one?
query Blog($language: LanguageCode, $blogHandle: String!, $first: Int, $last: Int, $startCursor: String, $endCursor: String) @inContext(language: $language) {
  blog(handle: $blogHandle) {
    title
    seo {
      title
      description
    }
    articles(
      first: $first
      last: $last
      before: $startCursor
      after: $endCursor
      reverse: true
    ) {
      nodes {
        ...ArticleItem
        metafields(identifiers: {namespace: "custom", key: "misc_content_long_text_1"}) {
          value
          references {
            edges {
              node
            }
          }
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasPreviousPage
        hasNextPage
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
        startCursor
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment ArticleItem on Article {
  author: authorV2 {
    name
  }
  contentHtml
  handle
  id
  image {
    id
    altText
    url
    width
    height
  }
  publishedAt
  title
  blog {
    handle
  }
}

My metafields include:

misc_content_long_text_1
misc_content_long_text_2
misc_content_long_text_3
misc_text_field_1
misc_text_field_2
misc_text_field_3
misc_text_field_4
misc_text_field_5

I'm hoping I don't have to call multiple queries to fetch those. TIA

You can achieve this by aliasing the meta fields. Here is the official documents https://www.shopify.com/in/partners/blog/how-to-use-graphql-aliases
query Blog($language: LanguageCode, $blogHandle: String!, $first: Int, $last: Int, $startCursor: String, $endCursor: String) @inContext(language: $language) {
  blog(handle: $blogHandle) {
    title
    seo {
      title
      description
    }
    articles(
      first: $first
      last: $last
      before: $startCursor
      after: $endCursor
      reverse: true
    ) {
      nodes {
        ...ArticleItem
        misc_content_long_text_1 : metafields(identifiers: {namespace: "custom", key: "misc_content_long_text_1"}) {
          value
          references {
            edges {
              node
            }
          }
        },
misc_text_field_2: metafields(identifiers: {namespace: "custom", key: "misc_text_field_2"}) {
          value
          references {
            edges {
              node
            }
          }
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasPreviousPage
        hasNextPage
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
        startCursor
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment ArticleItem on Article {
  author: authorV2 {
    name
  }
  contentHtml
  handle
  id
  image {
    id
    altText
    url
    width
    height
  }
  publishedAt
  title
  blog {
    handle
  }
}

